# Converting unsigned char * to char * string C

Tags: c, char, type-conversion, unsigned

I have code to convert an int into a unsigned char * as such:

```
int i = //a number <= 15;
unsigned char * byte = (unsigned char *) &i;
```

I do this because I need the byte value of of that int.
Later I want to attach this byte value to a `char *`, so I need to convert it to a string.

```
Ex. if: int i = 15;
then: unsigned char * byte = F;
```

However I need to convert this to get:

```
char * string = "F";
```

I have tried:

```
char * string = (char *) &byte;
//and
char * string = (char *) byte;
//or just straight up treating it like a char * by going:
printf("%s", byte);
```

and several other combinations, but they've all resulted in seg faults. Does anyone know how I can do this? Or even if there's an easier way of converting an int to the hexidecimal representation in a char?

I'm very new to C and appreciate any answers thank you.

Comment: If `0 <= i <= 15`, it looks like you want `unsigned char byte = (unsigned char)i;` and `char string[2] = {(char)byte, '\0'};`? Does that sound right, or is there more than one byte involved here? (And do you actually need `printf`, or would `putchar` work fine?)

Comment: `char byte[2]; sprintf(byte, "%X", (unsigned char)i); printf("%s", byte);`

Comment: Yes that's correct I actually only need one byte and not an array of bytes, so `unsigned char` suffices. I know "%X" is the way to print unsigned chars, but I actually want to append the converted `char` to an existing `char *`, and not JUST print it. (the print statements were really just for debugging)

Comment: and going `char character = (char) i` does not seem to work when `i` is a single unsigned char

Comment: you can use sprintf to append converted char to an existing char*, i.e. `sprintf(byte, "%s%X", mychar, (unsigned char)i);`

Comment: @Miradham Kamilov [That](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46762826/converting-unsigned-char-to-char-string-c#comment80471653_46762826) is not appending, but concatenation.  `sprintf()` is not good at _appending_.

Comment: Please edit all of these *comments* into your question so that it is coherent instead of this mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I [actually want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46762826/converting-unsigned-char-to-char-string-c#comment80471119_46762826) to append the converted char to an existing `char *`

1. Insure the destination is big enough.

   ```
   char existing[100];
   // existing is populated somehow, now to add the `unsigned char`
   size_t len = strlen(existing);
   // 2 is the max size of a 8-bit value printed in hex.  Adjust as needed.
   if (len + 2 >= sizeof existing) Error_BufferTooSmall();
   ```
2. Write to the end of the existing `char *`.

   ```
   // Only use the least significant `char` portion with `hh`
   sprintf(existing + len , "%hhX", (unsigned) i);
   ```

> `hh` Specifies that a following `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, or `X` conversion specifier applies to a signed char or unsigned char argument (the argument will have been promoted according to the integer promotions, but its value shall be
>   converted to `signed char` or `unsigned char` before printing); ...  C11 §7.21.6.1 7

Answer (score 1):

```c
int i = //a number <= 15;
unsigned char * byte = (unsigned char *) &i;
```

Is plain wrong.

What you are doing is taking the address of the integer variable `i` and putting into a pointer to an `unsigned char`.

From what I read I think you want to convert an integer to a character (or string).

You can do this with `itoa` or even easier with `sprintf`.

For example:

```c
#include <stdio.h> // printf, snprintf

int main(void) {
    int i = 255;
    char theIntegerAsString[5] = {0};

    if (snprintf(theIntegerAsString, sizeof(theIntegerAsString), "%X", i) > 0) {
        printf("The number %d in Hexadecimal is: %s\n", i, theIntegerAsString);
    }
}
```

You might wonder why I used `snprintf` instead of `sprintf`.

This is because `sprintf` does not always check the buffer size, whereas `snprintf` always does. See [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow).

Please note that `%X` is specific to the type `unsigned int` for larger or smaller types you need another specifier. I strongly recommend using `<stdint.h>` and `<inttypes.h>` like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h> // printf, snprintf
#include <stdint.h> // intX_t
#include <inttypes.h> // PRIx..

int main(void) {
    int32_t i = 255; // signed 32 bit integer
    char theIntegerAsString[5] = {0};

    if (snprintf(theIntegerAsString, sizeof(theIntegerAsString), "%" PRIX32, i) > 0) {
        printf("The number %" PRId32 " in Hexadecimal is: %s\n", i, theIntegerAsString);
    }
}
```